# Sending MIDI input from VMPK on a laptop to raspberry pi

Tags: usb, sound, keyboard, midi

I have a raspberry pi running a pygame python script that requires MIDI input. I have a MIDI keyboard and I have set up the Pi to work with a MIDI keyboard directly. What I want now is to have a virtual MIDI keyboard(in this case VMPK set up on my laptop) and send MIDI input from the laptop to the raspberry via USB. How can I do that?

Comment: You'd have to configure the Pi as a MIDI gadget.

Comment: Wouldn't the laptop be the MIDI device though, since i want it to send midi data to the Pi

Comment: The direction of the MIDI messages does not matter. The laptop is not capable of being a USB device, it's a USB host.